# Changing created system calls without recompiling

Tags: kernel, system-calls, kernel-module

So I've created system calls and compiled the kernel, but they didn't work like I wanted them to. Is there a way I can edit and debug them without recompiling over and over again?

I've seen examples of intercepting system calls using modules, but none for the kernel version I'm required to use (v3.3), which seems to work differently than the older versions I find examples for. Is there a way I can implement interception in this version?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/). It allows you to write a simple program to print information about your running system